# "rpm -qa kernel" command lists only older version of the kernel on CentOS. why?

Tags: linux-kernel, rpm

Typing `rpm -qa kernel` on CentOS terminal only shows kernel version 
- `3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64` but I do have `4.20.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` also installed and currently running.

```
$ rpm -qa kernel
kernel-3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
$uname -a
Linux SJFW4-H44 4.20.12-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Sat Feb 23 09:15:50 EST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Why is that the case? How do I fix it or any reliable alternative commands available?

Comment: Add some example output of `rpm -qa kernel` together with `uname -a` and grub config ?

Comment: @steve: Please see the screenshot attached in the answer section. Thanks for your time

Comment: Check your grub config.  Will likely list various kernels this box can boot from.

Comment: @steve: I can boot from either kernels during startup of the machine but not sure why rpm -qa kernel command shows only older version although I have 4.20 (higher version) installed.

Comment: Because a kernel package doesn't have to be named kernel. 4.20 must belong to some rpm lacking the name kernel....